# Term of dielectric constant in the expression of induced charge density dielectric medium kept in between the plates of parallel plate capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance, dielectric

Whenever a dielectric substance is kept in between the plates of a parallel plate capacitor, it gets polarized and there is a net electric field  developed which reduces the electric field between the plates which initially existed

Ef= the new electric field between the plates having dielectric substance

E⁰ = the initial field between the plates( there is no dielectric medium )

Ei= induced  electric field in the dielectric substance

K = dielectric constant of the medium

Y= electric permittivity of air

X⁰= charge/ area  of the parallel plate capacitor

Xi= charge induced/ area of the parallel plate capacitor

So
Ef= E⁰- Ei

(Ef= E⁰/K)

E⁰/K = E⁰ - Ei

Ei= E⁰- E⁰/K = E⁰( 1 - 1/K)............(i)

**now my book says.....**

E⁰ = x/y

Ei= Xi/y

I doubt that since the field lines in the dielectric are not passing through vacuum the correct expression should have been
Ei=Xi/kY

(As permittivity of a medium is = k×Y )

Ei= Xi/Y  =  X/Y(1-1/K)............( USING EQN i)

So Xi= X(1-1/K)

but according to me, this should have been Xi = KX(1-1/K)

Am I making any conceptual mistake here?